# Codeigniter + AngularJs + JqueryMobile no show items Json

Tags: javascript, php, json, angularjs, codeigniter

I 'm developing an application.
have a controler in Codignieter establishing a json

```
function  hotel_list(){
    $this->db->order_by('estabNome','asc');
    $query1 = $this->db->get('hotel');
    $json  = $query1->result();
    $JSON = json_encode($json);
    print_r($JSON);
}
```

This code generates the following array

```
[{"estabId":"1","estabName":"Hotel do Jo\u00e3o Mauricio","estabFone":"(12) 3333-3333","estabAdress":"Rua Brigadeiro Jord\u00e3o, 761 - Abern\u00e9ssia, Campos do Jord\u00e3o - SP, 12460-000, Brasil","estabAdressComplement":"Pr\u00f3ximo ao Center" ....}]
```

My html code that uses this array is

```
<div id="one" data-role="page">
    <div data-role="header">
            <a href="../index.html" data-ajax="false" data-icon="back">
                Back
            </a>
            <h1>Hotels</h1>
    </div><!-- /header -->      
    <div data-role="content">
        <div ng-app="" ng-controller="estabController">
            <ul data-role="listview" data-filter="true">
                <li ng-repeat="estab in item">
                    <a href="#detail" class="ui-btn ui-shadow ui-corner-all" data-rel="dialog" data-transition="pop">
                    <img ng-src="http://192.168.1.12/guia/001/assets/img/hotels/{{estab.img1}}" />
                    {{estab.estabName}}
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>        
        </div>   
    </div> 
</div>
<script>
function estabController($scope,$http){
    $http.get("http://192.168.1.12/guia/001/home/hotel_list")
    .success(function(response){$scope.item = response;});
}
</script> 

  <!-- Start of third page: #detal -->
   <div data-role="page" id="detail">
   <div data-role="header" data-theme="b">
      <h1>Content</h1>
   </div><!-- /header -->
   <div role="main" class="ui-content">
       <h2>Detalhes</h2>
      {{estab.estabNome}}
            <br/>    
            <a href="#one" data-rel="back" class="ui-btn ui-shadow ui-corner-all ui-btn-inline ui-icon-back ui-btn-icon-left">Close</a></p>
</div><!-- /content -->
<div data-role="footer">
    <h4>Page Footer</h4>
</div><!-- /footer -->
```

The system shows the correct list of items in the array generated via CodeIgniter , but to open Popup shows {{estab.estabName}}  and not the content of json array that should be the correct name of the hotel.
Can anyone guide me ?
Greetings from Sao Paulo / Brazil

Comment: Current versions of angular (1.3 + ) don't support global functions as controllers. What version are you using?

Comment: @charlietfl I'm using version  AngularJS v1.2.26

Answer (score 0):

If the double braces are shown in the view of the angular app, that usually means, that angular did not bootstrap correctly or JavaScript threw an error while parsing your script.

I suspect, that the Angular application is not loaded, due to the missing value in `ng-app`.

You could try and see the following in the browser console:

1. Does JavaScript throw an error?
2. Does the response of your request to CodeIgniter return the JSON array correctly in the network area of DevTools

Also you shouldn't use a function as a controller in the global scope. Try and use the Angular module system with dependency injection (http://dailyjs.com/2013/05/23/angularjs-injection/) to make sure that your application doesn't influence other libraries or isn't influenced by other libraries used in your browser page.

In this **simplified example** you should see, that using the module system correctly and defining value for `ng-app`, the application should be bootstrapped correctly: http://codepen.io/rias/pen/xbzyga